# Iterate through ViewData array and use javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an array that is passed through the ViewData to my view. This array is composed of several elements of one of my Models.

I want to iterate through these elements and use javascript code with elements of the object.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
for x in ViewData["asdasd"] {

  foo(x.Property)

}
```

foo is a javascript function.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection to get the value.  (edited because I realized I totally misunderstood the question at first)

```
@{ 
 Type t = typeof(MyModelType);
 foreach (string x in ViewData["mykey"])
 { 
     var propertyVal = t.GetProperty(x).GetValue(MyModelObject, null);
     @Html.Raw("foo('" + propertyVal + "')");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct try:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray = <%= ViewData[yourarray] %>;

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    foo(myArray[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
@{
foreach (var firstName in (ViewData["my_list"] as IEnumerable<string>)) {
    @Html.Raw(firstName);<br />
}
```

}